# 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, and ODE solving in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ode

I'm doing a heat Simulink work and I got an error saying "'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". I couldn't find that error came and how to fix that.

First I read a text document and make an array for the initial condition.(ycut)

Next, I'm creating a function "EPCMchg"

Then I'm doing a simulation using "odeint". Actually I'm converting MATLAB code and it has ODE45 differential equations solver. Its equivalent in python is odeint.
I read lots of documentation related to error "'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"" and odeint but couldn't catch the error.

If someone can help me, greatly appriciate it. Thanks in advance
Here are the code and error.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from math import sqrt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

ICHG = 1 #charge or ICHG=-1 discharge
print(ICHG)

df2 = pd.read_csv(ycut_file, sep=r'\s{2,}', engine='python', header=None, names=['Value'])
ycut = df2.to_numpy().flatten()

**Output:**
ycut:  [-4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01
  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02
 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01
  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02
 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01
  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02
 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01  5.500000e+02 -4.000000e+01
  5.500000e+02 -3.999990e+01  5.500001e+02 -3.999980e+01  5.500003e+02
 -3.999950e+01  5.500011e+02 -3.999840e+01  5.500034e+02 -3.999540e+01
  5.500098e+02 -3.998740e+01  5.500267e+02 -3.996830e+01  5.500675e+02
 -3.992660e+01  5.501580e+02 -3.984240e+01  5.503420e+02 -3.968600e+01
  5.506877e+02 -3.941640e+01  5.512901e+02 -3.898240e+01  5.522699e+02
 -3.832740e+01  5.537646e+02 -3.739550e+01  5.559138e+02 -3.613990e+01
  5.588393e+02 -3.453170e+01  5.626245e+02 -3.256610e+01  5.672970e+02
 -3.026550e+01  5.728186e+02 -2.767850e+01  5.790859e+02 -2.487450e+01
  5.859400e+02 -2.193520e+01  5.931861e+02 -1.894460e+01  6.006170e+02
 -1.597890e+01  6.080382e+02 -1.309800e+01  6.152899e+02 -1.034030e+01
  6.222625e+02 -7.719300e+00  6.289058e+02 -5.224500e+00  6.352294e+02
 -2.824200e+00  6.412981e+02 -4.698000e-01  6.472213e+02  1.899100e+00
  6.531412e+02  4.350000e+00  6.592214e+02  6.956000e+00  6.656405e+02
  9.798900e+00  6.725974e+02  1.298260e+01  6.803386e+02  1.666380e+01
  6.892234e+02  2.110970e+01  6.998522e+02  2.679910e+01  7.132907e+02
  3.458400e+01  7.314356e+02  4.593790e+01  7.575796e+02  6.331840e+01
  7.972448e+02  9.068090e+01  8.593479e+02  1.355955e+02  9.271171e+02]


def EPCMchg(x,t, NSTAGES,Tf1, Tf2, Tf3, Hf1, Hf2, Hf3,TankD, TankH, deltaz, porosity, dp,Cpf, kf, rhof, Cpb, kb, rhob,ufluid, mdotsaltflow, hotHTF):
    #Models an encapsulated Thermal Energy Storage system with multiple salt PCM Assumed salt properties 
     #for NaNO3 with freezing temp=frzHTF
    #(650F), cold HTF fluid from steam generator=coldHTF (550f),and hot temp from solar=hotHTF (1050F).
    #Intermediate Calculations of parameters used in differential equations
    # Surface area of Tank for calculating Mass velocity of fluid
    pi = 3.14159
    Atank = pi*TankD*TankD/4 #ft^2
    #Volume of each element of height deltaz
    deltaV = pi*TankD*TankD*deltaz/4 # ft^3
    #Properties of heat transfer fluid used in differential eqns
    rhocpf=rhof*Cpf*porosity # btu/ft3/F
    
    #Particle surface area per unit volume ft2/ft3
    dparticle=dp/304.8 #[ft] dp mm particle
    av=(6/dparticle) #ft2/ft3
    #heat transfer coefficnet inside particle (use a simple thermal conductivit/particle radius
    hsl0=kb/dparticle #heat transfer coeff particle solid, Btu/h/ft2/F
    #heat transfer coefficnet of liquid inside particle (use a simple thermal conductivit/particle radius 
     #150% of solid to account for convection
    hl0=hsl0*1.5 #heat transfer coeff particle liquid, Btu/h/ft2/F
    
    #Input fluid Temperature at top of the tank during charging from the solar field
    prevTf= hotHTF #deg F
    
    #Bottom Salt 1 is the bottom, NSTAGES=top
    
    rany =NSTAGES+1
    #xdot = np.zeros(rany)
    for STAGE in range(rany,0,-1):
        HbSTAGE = x[2*STAGE-1] #Solid Enthalpy (btu/lb)
        TfSTAGE = x[2*STAGE] # FLuid Temperature, F
        #[ Tf,Hf,dh ] = saltstage( STAGE )
        
        #Bottom Stages
        Tf,Hf,dh=Tf1,Hf1,0
        
        #Middle stages
        if STAGE > NSTAGES/3:
            Tf,Hf,dh=Tf3,Hf3,Cpb*(Tf-Tf1)
            
        #Top stages
        if STAGE > 2 * (NSTAGES/3):
            Tf,Hf,dh=Tf2,Hf2,Cpb*(Tf-Tf1)
            
        # Determine conditions inside capsules (molten, solid or fractional 
        #solid
        if HbSTAGE<(Hf+dh):
            xsolid=1-(HbSTAGE-dh)/Hf #fraction solidification inside capsule
            if xsolid<=0:
                xsolid=0
            else:
                xsolid=1
                
            TbSTAGE=Tf
            hsl=hsl0/sqrt(xsolid) #heat transfer coeff of solid varies as sqrt of soli farction
            hl=hl0/(1-sqrt(xsolid)) #heat transfer coeff of liquid remaining
            u=1/((1/ufluid)+(1/hsl)+(1/hl))

            uav=u*av
            tauconst=(mdotsaltflow*Cpf/Atank)/rhocpf #constnts in diff equations
            aconst=uav/rhocpf #constnts in diff equations
            cconst=uav/rhob/(1-porosity) #constnts in diff equations
            
            
        #solid cooling
        if HbSTAGE<dh:
            xsolid=1
            TbSTAGE = Tf+(HbSTAGE-dh)/Cpf
            hsl=hsl0/sqrt(xsolid)
            u=1/((1/ufluid)+(1/hsl))
            
            uav=u*av
            tauconst=(mdotsaltflow*Cpf/Atank)/rhocpf
            aconst=uav/rhocpf
            cconst=uav/rhob/(1-porosity)
            
        
        # sensible heat in liquid free convection hl=90
        if HbSTAGE>(Hf+dh):
            xsolid=0
            TbSTAGE=Tf+(HbSTAGE-Hf-dh)/Cpf
            hl=hl0/(1-sqrt(xsolid))
            u=1/((1/ufluid)+(1/hl))
            
            uav=u*av
            tauconst=(mdotsaltflow*Cpf/Atank)/rhocpf
            aconst=uav/rhocpf
            cconst=uav/rhob/(1-porosity)
            
        
            
        xdot[2*STAGE-1] = cconst*(TfSTAGE - TbSTAGE) # capsule enthalpy
        xdot[2*STAGE] = tauconst*(prevTf - TfSTAGE)+ aconst * (TbSTAGE-TfSTAGE) #HTF Temp
        
        #PREPARE FOR NEXT STAGE :
        prevTf = TfSTAGE
        
        xs[STAGE]=xsolid
        
    xs4=xs
    xdot = xdot
    return xs4,xdot;

## Start simulation:
t_final=4.0
tspan = np.linspace(0,t_final)
tspan
**Output:**
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
array([0.        , 0.08163265, 0.16326531, 0.24489796, 0.32653061,
       0.40816327, 0.48979592, 0.57142857, 0.65306122, 0.73469388,
       0.81632653, 0.89795918, 0.97959184, 1.06122449, 1.14285714,
       1.2244898 , 1.30612245, 1.3877551 , 1.46938776, 1.55102041,
       1.63265306, 1.71428571, 1.79591837, 1.87755102, 1.95918367,
       2.04081633, 2.12244898, 2.20408163, 2.28571429, 2.36734694,
       2.44897959, 2.53061224, 2.6122449 , 2.69387755, 2.7755102 ,
       2.85714286, 2.93877551, 3.02040816, 3.10204082, 3.18367347,
       3.26530612, 3.34693878, 3.42857143, 3.51020408, 3.59183673,
       3.67346939, 3.75510204, 3.83673469, 3.91836735, 4.        ])

if ICHG == 1:
      [tchg, ychg]=odeint(EPCMchg,ycut,tspan,args=(NSTAGES, Tf1, Tf2, Tf3, Hf1, Hf2, Hf3,TankD, TankH, 
       deltaz, porosity, dp,Cpf, kf, rhof, Cpb, kb, rhob, ufluid, mdotsaltflow, hotHTF))
       plt.plot(tchg, ychg)
       plt.show()

**Output:**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-4b38269782f5> in <module>
      1 #call ode45 with function EPCMchg to charge
      2 if ICHG == 1:
----> 3     [tchg, ychg]=odeint(EPCMchg,ycut,tspan,args=(NSTAGES, Tf1, Tf2, Tf3, Hf1, Hf2, Hf3,TankD, TankH, deltaz, porosity, dp,Cpf, kf, rhof, Cpb, kb, rhob, ufluid, mdotsaltflow, hotHTF))
      4     plt.plot(tchg, ychg)
      5     plt.show()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg, tfirst)
    239     t = copy(t)
    240     y0 = copy(y0)
--> 241     output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    242                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
    243                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords,

<ipython-input-11-6746119c69d3> in EPCMchg(x, t, NSTAGES, Tf1, Tf2, Tf3, Hf1, Hf2, Hf3, TankD, TankH, deltaz, porosity, dp, Cpf, kf, rhof, Cpb, kb, rhob, ufluid, mdotsaltflow, hotHTF)
     26     rany =NSTAGES+1
     27     #xdot = np.zeros(rany)
---> 28     for STAGE in range(rany,0,-1):
     29         HbSTAGE = x[2*STAGE-1] #Solid Enthalpy (btu/lb)
     30         TfSTAGE = x[2*STAGE] # FLuid Temperature, F

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: In your function, `rany` is supposed to be an int, an argument to python `range`.  Looks like it is derived from `NSTAGES`.  That variable is passed through, so digging in `odeint` won't help you.  Read the traceback carefully.

Comment: The return type of `odeint` is also wrong, it just returns the `ychg` array, the times are the ones given as argument `tspan`. If you want comparable behavior to `ode45`, use `solve_ivp` with its default stepper `RK45`.

Comment: Check if you use python 3 but assumed that a simple division `a/b` is still integer division in the construction of `NSTAGES`, if so, use `a//b`. Unfortunately, you did not show the part of the script where `NSTAGES` is set, so one can only guess.

Comment: @hpaulj @LutzLehmann Thanks for the comments. I'm using python 3. ``` NSTAGES ``` I've imported from a text file and it's 60.0.  Do you think it's still giving some problem?

Comment: 60.0 is a float.  See the '.0' ?